# Target 'Pods' - Remove Duplicate References in Build Phase

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, build, cocoapods

Everytime I open my Cocoapods-generated `xcworkspace`, it gives me this warning along with a message:

```
The Copy Headers build phase contains duplicate references for one or more files.
This will remove the duplicate file references.
```

What's causing this error? Is the problem being caused by something in a specific pod? How do I permanently fix this?

Answer (score 1):

you may added a file manually that is already there in pods.Check if there some file exist twice and remove it if manually added

Run `pod install` again

Comment: Is there a way I can actually look the the copy headers build phase to see what the duplicate references are?